# Is there any way to override pyyaml's liberal handling of boolean values?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

It looks like pyyaml implements part of the [YAML 1.1 spec](http://yaml.org/type/bool.html), which allows a lot of different values to be interpreted as true or false:

Canonical:

```
y|n
```

Regexp:

```
y|Y|yes|Yes|YES|n|N|no|No|NO
 |true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE
 |on|On|ON|off|Off|OFF`
```

---

```
>>> for k in "y|Y|yes|Yes|YES|n|N|no|No|NO|true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE|on|On|ON|off|Off|OFF".split("|"):
...   print k, yaml.safe_load(k)
...
y y
Y Y
yes True
Yes True
YES True
n n
N N
no False
No False
NO False
true True
True True
TRUE True
false False
False False
FALSE False
on True
On True
ON True
off False
Off False
OFF False
```

and yet it serializes them to `true` or `false` (in contrast to with YAML 1.1's canonical `y` and `n`):

```
>>> yaml.safe_dump(dict(x=True, y=False))
'{x: true, y: false}\n'
```

Is there any way to override it so that only the canonical `true` and `false` values are interpreted as booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following to make PyYAML not to recognise those strings as booleans:

- replace the added implicit resolver that was added in `resolver.py`, and that by default reads:

  ```
  Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(
          u'tag:yaml.org,2002:bool',
          re.compile(ur'''^(?:yes|Yes|YES|no|No|NO
                      |true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE
                      |on|On|ON|off|Off|OFF)$''', re.X),
          list(u'yYnNtTfFoO'))
  ```

  you will have to trace the `add_implicit_resolver` to see where it adds what as there is no `remove_implicit_resolver`. Alternatively define a complete new `ResolverBase` subclass, that does everything `Resolver` does, but doesn't have the definition for `2002:bool` as above, but the restricted (1.2) version.
- update the `bool_values` class attribute of `SafeConstructor` in `constructor.py`

That doesn't make PyYAML 1.2 compatible, as there is more to that and PyYAML doesn't fully implement the YAML 1.1 specification to start with.

The easiest way to load YAML into python and not have Yes be interpreted as a boolean is using ruamel.yaml instead of PyYAML (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). In its sources you can also find how to keep the parser 1.1 compatible if the file is tagged as YAML 1.1 (if there is no tag ruamel.yaml assumes version 1.2).